# Calculating $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{k+1}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Hello everyone how can I calculate the sum of:

$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{k+1}$

I tried to use pascal identity and the binomial theorem and didn't success.

Someone can help me please?

Comment: Set $n=m-1$ and use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94719/proving-k-binomnk-n-binomn-1k-1

Comment: [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2915549/sum-of-the-series-sum-k-0n-frac1k1-binomnk?noredirect=1)

Answer (score 4):

Notice that : $${n \choose k}\frac{1}{k+1}={n+1 \choose k+1}\frac{1}{n+1}$$
The sum is 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n+1 \choose k+1}\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{2^{n+1}-1}{n+1}$$

---

Another possible solution is
$$(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}x^k$$
We can integrate both sides to get
$$\int_0^1(1+x)^ndx=\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}\int_0^1x^kdx=\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}\frac{1}{k+1}$$
The LHS is simply $\frac{2^{n+1}-1}{n+1}$ which gives the final result.
Hope this helps.